# C++ copy constructor: field with list of pointers

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am trying to create a copy constructor for my class A that contains a list of pointers of type B. The way I was trying to do it is as follows:

```
class A
{
 private:
   list<B*> myList;
   list<B*>::iterator iter;

public:
  A()
  {
   }

 // Copy constructor
 A(const A &src)
  {
    myList.assign(src.myList.begin(), src.myList.end());
  }

A& operator= (const A &src);

 };

A& A::operator= (const A &src)
{
// do the copy
myList.assign(src.myList.begin(), src.myList.end());

// return the existing object
return *this;
}
```

Now, my problem is that if I do this:

```
A=a1;

//call function that will change a1

A  a2(a1);

//call function that will change a1
```

Then after calling this last function that changes a1, I notice that a2 has changed too. I thought that the copy constructor is supposed to prevent this from happening, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: "that changes a1, I notice that a2 has changed too". Does this apply to elements contained in the list? In the sense that modifying an element will modify it even in the other object?

Comment: Imagine a phone book, in it the names, numbers, and addresses of everyone in town. Now you give a *copy* of the phone book to your buddy. Does that in *any* way mean the "Bob Jones" in his phone book is suddently somehow different than the "Bob Jones" in *your* phone book? Yeah, a copy of a list of just-pointers is pretty much that spot-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `std::list` is a list of pointers.
Your copy constructor performs a **shallow copy** of these pointers. After the copy constructor call both `a1` and `a2` are lists whose elements point to same objects.
If you want to avoid this, either:

1. Simply store objects rather than pointers in the `std::list` member or
2. Your copy constructor should perform a **deep copy**.

Assigning one pointer to another performs a shallow copy. In simple words, after the assignment both pointers point to the same object. Your code is roughly **[equivalent to](http://codepad.org/ElY5ibnn)**:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *ptr = &i;
    int *ptr2 = ptr;

    std::cout<<"\ni = "<<i;
    std::cout<<"\n*ptr = "<<*ptr;
    std::cout<<"\n*ptr2 = "<<*ptr2;

    *ptr2 = 20;

    std::cout<<"\ni = "<<i;
    std::cout<<"\n*ptr = "<<*ptr;
    std::cout<<"\n*ptr2 = "<<*ptr2;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
i = 10
*ptr = 10
*ptr2 = 10
i = 20
*ptr = 20
*ptr2 = 20
```

Comment: I think I understand this, but I believed that the default copy constructor of list made a deep copy of the elements. Now I see why this is happening. Is there a way to make a deep copy of the lists then?

Comment: @FranXh: Allocate memory to each pointed element separately,create a pointer to point to that memory, store the new pointer in the list. Simpler way is to simply store objects as elements and not pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Your current copy constructor is actually equivalent to the copy constructor that would be automatically generated if you didn't implement one yourself: it copies all the elements of the list, which are pointers. If you copy a list object and make changes to the original (such as adding or removing elements), those changes won't be reflected in the copy. But changes to the objects stored in the list **will** be reflected in the copy, because the lists only store pointers to them. If you don't want that behavior, you have to store actual B objects in the list:

```
list<B> mylist;
```

Of course that means that B must be copyable.